# Unable to fill edit fields from Shadow DOM using Playwright

Tags: javascript, css, ui-automation, shadow-dom, playwright

I have been trying to automate and  fill a login page using Playwright  and the fields are listed under a shadow DOM. I can get to the shadow (I believe) but finding the #email (CSS) does not happen consistently and times out or finds more than one. Can someone help me and tell what am I missing or doing wrong? App is CANVAS/Flutter and not very friendly exposing locators and interaction with tools and inspecting the elements isn't possible. Looks like I am not getting the right element/CSS [email/password].
I tried to enforce Click, Focus, Tab and double click but nothing seems to work consistently. However, while script is running in Debugging mode and after the First Tab (Email), I manually click the field, it fills the string but again looses context or doesn't find remaining objects.

import {test, expect} from '@playwright/test'

```
test.describe('Shadow DOM',
  () => {
    test('Fill Login page', async ({
      page,
    }) => {
     await page.goto('https://staging.edisoninteractive.tv/')
     await page.fill("#email", "abcyser@test.com")
     await page.click('#email',{button:"left"})
     await page.keyboard.press("Tab") // need to tab since unable to focus/click the field
    // await page.isVisible("text='current-password'")
     //await page.fill('#current-password', 'djjdjdjjdj')
     await page.locator('input[name="current-password"]').first().fill('dkkdkdkdkkd');
     //await page.locator('#current-password').click({ force: true });
    //  await page.dispatchEvent("#current-password",'click') 
      await page.keyboard.press("Enter")
    })
  }
)
page.fill: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "#current-password"
  selector resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one.
  selector resolved to hidden <input placeholder="" type="password" id="current-passw…/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Xwz.png)

Comment: I don't think I can run your site but the code looks OK to me and works on a contrived shadow root example to try to recreate your site's behavior using `const div = document.querySelector("div"); const shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: "open"}); shadow.innerHTML = \`<div><input id="current-password"></div>\`;`

Comment: What i see from the screenshot is that the input have height:0, width:0 so the check for visalibty is not passing.
Quote: Element is considered visible when it has non-empty bounding box and does not have visibility:hidden computed style. Note that elements of zero size or with display:none are not considered visible.
https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability#visible

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. I even tried with first(), nth(1), last() but no luck. Here's the output for the recent. 
Error: strict mode violation: "input#current-password:visible" resolved to 2 elements:
    1) <input placeholder="" type="password" autocorrect="on" …/> aka playwright.$("input[name="current-password"] >> nth=0")
    2) <input placeholder="" type="password" autocorrect="on" …/> aka playwright.$("input[name="current-password"] >> nth=1")

Comment: Please [edit] your post if you have more code to add. It's unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, there are 2 elements with the same identifier and you are trying to interact with the element that is hidden. You can resolve this issue by using **':visible'** pseudo class and your locator should look like this

```
await page.locator('input#current-password:visible').fill('your password here');
```